Area of tight-angled $\triangle POB$ given extensions of $OP,BP$ to circle centred at $O$ through $B$?
We have a triangle  $(\triangle POB)$ within a semicircle. $OP$ and $BP$ are extended to  $OA$  and  $BQ$.  $AP = 5$  and $PQ = 7$. What is the area of the triangle?

It's a problem I stumbled upon on chance. I haven't been able to solve it since I am a little weak in geometry.
The best approach I have tried is connecting  $Q$  to the diameter of semi circle and then approaching the two triangles as similar triangles as they both are right angled triangles.
I am still new to the site and can't quite use MathJax to round up the problem. I hope you all will see my mistakes lightly.
Thank You

It is known that if two chords intersect, then product of their segments is the same (see Intersecting chords theorem). In the picture two chords intersect at point $P$, if you continue the vertical one. $PB$ is found from the Pythagorean theorem. Hence
$$5\cdot (2r-5)=7\cdot \sqrt{r^2+(r-5)^2}$$
$$25\cdot(4r^2-20r+25)=49\cdot(2r^2-10r+25)$$
$$2r^2-10r-600=0$$
$$r=-15,\quad r=20$$
Since $2r-5$ is positive, $r=20$. Then the area is $$\frac{r(r-5)}2=\frac{20\cdot15}2=150.$$

I never thought there could be a simple answer like this. I once saw the chord theorem you mentioned on MindYourDecision's youtube channel. But I was short-sighted that I couldn't think of that approach. It really is a great answer that doesn't need complicated processes. I sincerely appreciate that you took some time to answer the question I was struggling with. Thank you very much

@AfsarAhmed Glad to help! Intersecting chords theorem is indeed a very powerful tool.

If we could solve for the radius $r$, we would have enough information to compute $|\triangle OPB|$.  We know $OP = r-5$ and $OB = r$.  So $PB = \sqrt{r^2 + (r-5)^2}$ by the Pythagorean theorem.
Consequently, $QB = 7 + PB$, and because $\triangle QOB$ is isosceles with $OQ = OB = r$, the midpoint $M$ of $QB$ forms two congruent right triangles, both of which are similar to the yellow right triangle since $\angle MBO = \angle PBO$.
So now we have enough information to set up an equation that we can solve for $r$: since $\triangle MBO \sim \triangle OBP$,
$$\frac{MB}{OB} = \frac{OB}{PB}.$$  Since $MB = \frac{7 + PB}{2}$ we obtain
$$\frac{7 + \sqrt{r^2 + (r-5)^2}}{2r} = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + (r-5)^2}}.$$
The remainder of the solution is left as an exercise.

Thank you for answering the question heropup. It may sound like I am faking, but I almost reached the conclusion with my approach. But gave up midway seeing nothing was working. But thanks to you, I got confidence and inspiration to try even when nothing's working.  It's like life motivation. Thanks anyway brother
